# endless scroll on listview with kotlin and tornadofx

Tags: listview, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I wanna implement endless scroll for listview.

The app receives data from server portionally and currently it shows only last 50 rows. 
I'm using `tornadofx`, here's the code:

`MainController.kt`:

```
private fun setAllServerHistoryList() {
        if (curSelectedLogId != -1) {
            serverHistoryList.clear()
            runAsync {
                serverAPI.getServerHistory(curSelectedLogId)
            } ui {
                serverHistoryList.setAll(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

`MainView.kt`:

```
private val historyListView = listview(controller.serverHistoryList) {
        selectionModel = NoSelectionModel()
        cellFormat{...}
}
```

`getServerHistory` makes `GET` request to server and returns parsed data, I can easily ask other rows using `offset` and `count` parameters.

But I haven't realized yet how can I add listener to detect `amount of rows left` to both sides of list (in case if I'm opening view not from the bottom but in range of 10000:10200), and how to add data to existing list with avoiding memory errors.

I've already read lots of answers about same question but most of them (if not all) about android and java apps.

Thanks in advance for all the responds.

UPD with rewritten solution from answers (cheers to [@TornadoFX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8151834/tornadofx-fan)):

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell
import javafx.util.Callback
import tornadofx.*


data class ScrollableItemWrapper(val data : String, val lastItem : Boolean = false) {

    val id = nextId() // always increasing

    companion object {
        private var idgen = 1 // faux static class member
        fun nextId() = idgen++
    }
}


class EndlessScrollView : View("Endless Scroll") {

    var currentBatch = 1

    var last_batch = 0

    val TOTAL_NUM_BATCHES = 10

    private val records = FXCollections.observableArrayList<ScrollableItemWrapper>()

    override val root = listview(records) {
        selectionModel = NoSelectionModel()

        cellFactory = Callback { listView ->

            object : ListCell<ScrollableItemWrapper>() {

                private val listener = ChangeListener<Number> { obs, ov, nv ->
                    if ( userData != null ) {
                        val scrollable = userData as ScrollableItemWrapper
                        val pos = listView.height - this.height - nv.toDouble()
                        if ( scrollable.lastItem && pos > 0 && (pos < this.height) && index < last_batch*50) {
                            val currentPos = index
                            runAsync {
                                getNextBatch()
                            } ui {
                                listView.scrollTo(currentPos)
                                records.addAll( it )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                init {
                    layoutYProperty().addListener(listener)
                }

                override fun updateItem(item: ScrollableItemWrapper?, empty: Boolean) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty)
                    if( item != null && !empty ) {
                        text = "[${item.id}]" + item.data
                        userData = item
                    } else {
                        text = null
                        userData = null
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    init {
        records.addAll( getNextBatch() )
    }

    private fun getNextBatch() : List<ScrollableItemWrapper> {
        if( currentBatch < TOTAL_NUM_BATCHES  ) {
            last_batch++
            return 1.rangeTo(50).map {
                ScrollableItemWrapper("Batch ${currentBatch} Record ${it}", it == 50)
            }.apply {
                currentBatch++
            }.toList()
        } else {
            return emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code which I've used in a plain JavaFX app.  It relies on a side effect that has worked through multiple versions of JavaFX.  A wrapper class is used to pair the data with a flag indicating whether or not an item is the last in a batch.  In the cell factory, a listener is registered and activated when the layoutY property is given space.  If layoutY increases from 0 -- implying that the cell is shown -- and the last item flag is set, more data is fetched.

That data is added but the scroll position is saved so that the ListView doesn't jump through the whole fetched set.

```
data class ScrollableItemWrapper(val data : String, val lastItem : Boolean = false) {

  val id = nextId() // always increasing

  companion object {
    private var idgen = 1 // faux static class member
    fun nextId() = idgen++
  }
}
class EndlessScrollView : View("Endless Scroll") {

    var currentBatch = 1

    val TOTAL_NUM_BATCHES = 10

    val records = mutableListOf<ScrollableItemWrapper>().observable()

    override val root = listview(records) {
        cellFactory = Callback {

            object : ListCell<ScrollableItemWrapper>() {

                private val listener = ChangeListener<Number> { obs, ov, nv ->
                    if ( userData != null ) {
                        val scrollable = userData as ScrollableItemWrapper
                        if( scrollable.lastItem &&
                            ((listView.height - this.height - nv.toDouble()) > 0.0)) {

                            val currentPos = index
                            runAsync {
                                getNextBatch()
                            } ui {
                                listView.scrollTo(currentPos)
                                records.addAll( it )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                init {
                    layoutYProperty().addListener(listener);
                }

                override fun updateItem(item: ScrollableItemWrapper?, empty: Boolean) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty)
                    if( item != null && !empty ) {
                        text = "[${item.id}]" + item.data!!
                        userData = item
                    } else {
                        text = null
                        userData = null
                    }
                }

                protected fun finalize() {
                    layoutYProperty().removeListener(listener)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        records.addAll( getNextBatch() )
    }

    private fun getNextBatch() : List<ScrollableItemWrapper> {
        if( currentBatch <= TOTAL_NUM_BATCHES  ) {
            return 'A'.rangeTo('Z').map {
                ScrollableItemWrapper("Batch ${currentBatch} Record ${it}", it == 'Z')
            }.apply {
                currentBatch++
            }.toList()
        } else {
            return emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even though it seems to be correct in general, my view is completely different as using cellFactory seems to be inappropriate. May be that's because of your `dataclass`, my `serverHistoryList` is: `val serverHistoryList: ObservableList<ServerEvent> = FXCollections.observableArrayList()` where `ServerEvent` is one of possible kinds of update (at current version updates are working correctly).

Comment: also it complains on `Callback` and `ListCell`

Comment: If you prefer FXCollections, this will work too  `val records = FXCollections.observableArrayList<ScrollableItemWrapper>()`.  Make sure that the wrapper class is the type.  The wrapper class is the means by which the data tells the cellFactory which item should trigger the retrieval call.  That might be the source of your compilation problems with the generic in Callback and ListCell.

Comment: cellFactory usually is limited to an updateItem() and in TornadoFX this can be further streamlined to cellFormat.  A few years ago, I had expected ListView.onScrollFinished() to activate a callback when the user stopped scrolling.  However, even in the current version of Java, this doesn't seem to do anything on the desktop with a mouse scroll.  The hack IMO is more on the layoutY>0 than the factory.

Comment: I haven’t tried to implement it with updates from comments yet, but if I would scroll through thousands of rows - how would be data stored in memory? For example when in Telegram app you searching messages by text and finding one in the very middle of history, gap between <last> and <needed> ranges seems to be empty but still easily managed by view. I wish I could achieve the same result

Comment: And also, may be you know how to store data about last viewed object because whenever you switch between views its better to continue seeing from last saved index. I’m already caching array in memory but as I’m unable to get exact position it seems to be impossible to restore the state.

Comment: For RAM usage, the ObservableList is accruing more and more objects but the JavaFX ListCell Nodes are recycled.  Lets say each message is 200 bytes, if you have 10Mb to spare, you could scroll around 50,000 messages.

Comment: Right now, I'm marking the lastItem when I retrieve a batch from my service call.  This could be expanded to include more information returned by the service.  For instance, you could change my lastItem flag to "needed" and then if the service returns 0 records, you could use the "last" item.  We're discussing a general solution on the TornadoFX Slack (kotlinlang.slack.com) that will probably build off of the wrapper class to include a paging abstraction.

Comment: `listView.height - this.height - nv.toDouble()) > 0.0` - is weak point in code, which makes it asking for next batch whenever `scrollable.lastitem` is `true` (is visible). If, for example, you have 50 rows on screen and one of them counts as `lastitem` it would ask for `50+frames`x new batches.
Already rewriting it, will post a result

Comment: Updated my post with own version of yours, works fine for me with no bugs. 
Last question, how can I revert view (to start from the bottom)?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact requirement, but if you're returning to new instance of the ListView and need to repeat the retrieval, you could save off the last position along with a second variable of the number of retrievals.  Then, the program would be modified to "prime" the ListView with not just a single fetch, but with several fetches based on # of retrievals.  You'll have enough items to make the scrollTo() valid.  Be sure to check out the TornadoFX channel: kotlinlang.slack.com.